# Need right-alignment of item numbers in enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I am an occasional LaTeX user

Using this code

```
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1.]

    \item 
    Risolvere l'equazione $\left( x^3-5\right)^4$

    \item 
    Dopo aver imposto...
\end{enumerate}
```

I have got this result

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you load the `enumitem` package and start the `enumerate` environment as follows:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\arabic*., ref=\arabic*, align=right]
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\arabic*., ref=\arabic*, align=right]
\item a 
\item b \addtocounter{enumi}{5}
\item h
\item i
\item j
\item k
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

(If you don't need to cross-reference any of the enumerated items, you may omit the `ref=\arabic*` option.)

Answer (score 2):

I use `paralist` and its options :

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1.]
\setcounter{enumi}{8}
\item 
Risolvere l'equazione $\left( x^3-5\right)^4$

\item 
Dopo aver imposto...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```